# sql spatial select linestring parts within polygon using stintersection

Tags: sql, sql-server, polygon, geography

Trying to get rows with parts of geographic linestrings that are within a polygon.
Microsoft SQL.

Table: RSACLL
Column name: Contour is a geography column.

Every Contour column in each row already contains valid linstrings; already being used with a C# project. Instead of using C#, I would like to you SQL statements to select parts of each linestring that are within a specific polygon. The following statements issue error:

> 4104, RSACLL.Contour could not be bound.

Please help me with providing the correct SQL statement. Thx.

```
DECLARE @g geography;  
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-26.66532915 28.58125953, -26.66532915 28.63808831, -26.63020797 28.63808831, -26.63020797 28.58125953))', 4326);  
SELECT @g.STIntersection(RSACLL.Contour)
```

Comment: You need a `FROM` clause.

Comment: DECLARE @g geography;  
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-26.66532915 28.58125953, -26.66532915 28.63808831, -26.63020797 28.63808831, -26.63020797 28.58125953))', 4326);  
SELECT @g.STIntersection(RSACLL.Contour) from RSACLL     worked ... query started to execute ... 6522  The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance because it exceeds a single hemisphere.  ...

Comment: lat longs wrong way round and poly was not closed